# Inferring independence from conditional expectation

Tags: random-variables, independence

Given two random variables $X,Y$ defined on the same probability space, if $E[X|Y]$ is not a function of $Y$ can we say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  It is permisable for $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)$ to be constant , but have $X$ dependent on $Y$.

You can surely imagine a distribution where the *conditional expected value* for $X$ given $Y$ is constant, but have the *realised values for* $X$ be restricted by values for $Y$.

> Consider $(X,Y)\sim\mathcal U\{(0,1),(1,0),(2,1)\]$

Comment: Could you please explain your example distribution?

Comment: Resolved. Thank  you.

Comment: Constants are also functions.

Answer (score 0):

We can always express $E(X|Y)$ as $f(Y)$ for some measurable function $f: \mathbb  R \to \mathbb  R$ (whether or not there is independence).